# payment gateway for IOS and android

Tags: android, ios, payment-gateway

I am developing an app in which users have to pay via app(android/ios) in Australian restaurants.

There are two optioins to pay via PayPal or via credit/debit/atm card.

Is there any payment api which gives both options to pay, means user can pay via paypal account or via any bank card(eg. credit card, debit card, master card etc.)

Please suggest me which api should I use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `PayPal` sdk for this. PayPal have both iOS and Android sdk's.

Please check this link to download the SDK's and for tutorials: [PayPal SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/)

There is option for credit card payment also.But, according to [PayPal Docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/accept-credit-cards/):

> Direct credit card payment and related features are restricted in some
>   countries.

Comment: does paypal sdk give functionality to pay via credit/atm/debit/master etc cards. ?

Comment: @rahul: thanks for the comment. All the best, happy coding.