# Payment gateway integration in android application

Tags: android, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I want to integrate payment gateway in my application

1. I don't want to use `Google In-App` purchase
2. I don't want `Paypal` integration.

I have tried these API but this is not what I want, I want credit and debit card  based payment gateway. User choose card type,all details related to card and can make an order.

Comment: Have you checked CCAvenue

Comment: @YogeshLakhotia nop..not yet can you give me some reference please

Comment: check site [link](http://www.ccavenue.com/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [payment gateway for IOS and android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632824/payment-gateway-for-ios-and-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are dozens of payment gateway APIs out there to pick from. If you're up to building your own checkout page, adopting the PCI regulations, than you can pick for example Stripe, BrainTree, Authorize.net or Cybersource.
If you want to make it easier, pick a hosted solution like Zooz, BlueSnap, Avangate, etc.

Comment: Great absolutely nice n easy   hosted soultions

Comment: :does they given support for india as wellor  they are only for us ,uk?

Comment: India is a bit of a challenge as the Indian regulations demand that credit card processing is done in country (for tax reasons i assume). If you need to process Indian based businesses, than your options are limited to providers such as PayU.in or EBS.

Comment: @Tal Can you please refer me some url for how to integrate of PayUMoney in android application? I did google lot but no luck.

Comment: Just as a caution, Stripe is not PCI compliant. They just make so much money that they opt to pay the fines, from my understanding.